# Start chapter numbers with 1 in every new part of document

Tags: lyx

I'm using [André Miede's classicthesis](https://www.miede.de/#classicthesis) for Lyx. However, I couldn't figure out how to globally reset the chapter number after the start of a new part. This is how the TOC looks right now:

- Part 1

  - 1 Chapter
  - 1 Chapter
- Part 2

  - 3 Chapter

But I want it to look like this:

- Part 1

  - 1 Chapter
  - 1 Chapter
- Part 2

  - 1 Chapter

Every help is appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}` to your preamble to add the chapter to the list of counters which are reset at the start of a new part

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{title 1}

\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}

\part{title 2}

\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent work!

Comment: @Anti Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to reset the proper counter at the start of a part.

For instance:

```
\newcommand{\mypart}[1]{\setcounter{chapter}{0} % reset chapter counter
                         \part{#1}              % then create the part
}
```

Then you can simply use `\mypart` instead of `\part` and the numbering will be as you wish.